# firebase queryendingatValue("") always returns first child in database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a keyword search using firebase queries but they do not seem to ever retrieve the correct value.  Its always the first child of the database.  the database is organized using child by autoid. my data looks like this

```
posts :
-KJj6DMQVcaOIBZ76X03
      category: 
         "cleaner"
      dishname: 
         "Lysol"
        likes
      8QCQPfShSTdYe1VbCxHK4dkJPFj1: 
         true
      likesCount: 
           1
       picURL: 
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dis..."
       poster: 
      "8QCQPfShSTdYe1VbCxHK4dkJPFj1"
       price: 
         "$5"
       restaurant: 
         "house"
-KJj6PaHt9EfXQ5-EU-m

-KJnTUcb3BvZDMI0Pxgo

-KJnTl4giuy5QMvdeEo5
```

the function that is doing the search looks like this

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    filteredPosts.removeAll()
    let postref = firebase.child("posts")
    let  search = searchController.searchBar.text!
    print(search)
    let postQ = (postref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEndingAtValue(search))
    // postQ.keepSynced(true)
    postQ.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    self.filteredPosts.append(snapshot)
    print(snapshot)
    self.shouldShowSearchResults = 2
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

It is super frustrating. please help

Comment: you are querying against dishname or category ?

Comment: on which child, you want to search ... category, dishname, or on what that should define in your firebase reference

Comment: I want to query against everyone of them.  This code actually returned proper results at first than stopped @Shubhank

Answer (score 1):

**You are ordering by key**, `postref.queryOrderedByKey()`, and then querying by that key's value `queryEndingAtValue(search)`.

So unless your `search` variables is one of the `childByAutoId` values (`-KJnTUcb3BvZDMI0Pxgo`), I don't think you'll get back what you want.

**Instead order by the child property you are searching against.** Let's say you want to search by a post's `category`.

```
var search = "cleaner"
let categoryQuery = postref
   .queryOrderedByChild("category")
   .queryEndingAtValue(search)
```

This would pull back the record of `-KJj6DMQVcaOIBZ76X03`.

Comment: I want to query all the fields though

Comment: You can only query by one child value. You can restructure your data to allow further querying like posts/cleaner/$id.